# Refresh Background image in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, background, background-image

Is there any others alternatives to refresh the background image in VB.Net?

I used to use Me.Refresh() it is too slow.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a background image?  Do you mean the `BackgroundImage` property of a form or control?  Why do you need it refreshed?  How long does a call to `Refresh` take and how exactly have you determined what constitutes "too slow"?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to refresh the current image. The only way is `Me.Refresh()` but if your refresh mean is you want to change your background image after few min or sec then i prefer `Timer`
Use

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.BackgroundImage = "your_image.png"
    Me.Refresh() ' Optional, Not Important
End Sub
```

**and what do you mean by too slow?**

Comment: This is a poor question to begin with but one of the few things it does say is that `Refresh` is not good so an answer that says to use `Refresh` is not a good answer.

Comment: The OP does so in his question. _"I used to use Me.Refresh() it is too slow."_